# Isomorphism between two magmas with one.

Tags: computational-mathematics, gap, computational-algebra, magma

Do we have a method to find one (or all) isomorphism between two given magmas with one using GAP?

---

**Edit**

If we have **Loop** or **Latin square** (with one) instead of **Magma** then do we have the method?

Comment: This is already an undecidable problem for groups.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan There is a gap package "loops" in which [there](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/loops/doc/manual.pdf) is something related to it. So I was thinking that there should be a method.

Comment: @LaxmikantMishra: yes, LOOPS manual claims it is capable of doing this for loops.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Would you please elaborate the method (manual is not so easy to understand).

Comment: @LaxmikantMishra: Have you tried [`IsomorphismLoops( L, M )`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/loops/htm/CHAP006.htm#SECT012) in particular?

Comment: @LaxmikantMishra: what is a "Latin square (with one)" however? Is this possible?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: A latin square in which elements of first row and first column are same (in rough language).

Comment: @LaxmikantMishra: thanks, now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

The LOOPS package for GAP is designed for finite loops, for which the isomorphism problem is of course very much decidable.

If $L, M$ are finite loops, the method $\operatorname{IsomorphismLoops}(L,M)$ returns an isomorphism from $L$ to $M$, if it exists, else it returns "fail".

To calculate all isomorphisms from $L$ to $M$, it suffices to calculate $\operatorname{AutomorphismGroup}(M)$, and compose the above isomorphism with all elements of the automorphism group.

The methods of the LOOPS package can be modified to find isomorphisms among magmas with 1.